# Probability to find the treasure five times in row

Tags: probability

Let's pretend there are 10 doors in front of me. Behind one of them, there is a treasure and nothing behind all the others. Intuitively, I can easily determine I have 1 chance out of 10 the pick open the right door (the one with the treasure). I repeat this 5 times (i.e. all door closed, open one door). What are my chance to find the treasure the five times?

In brief, I am wondering how to determine the probably that I find the threasure 5 times in row.

Thansk

Comment: As @Edward pointed out, please add some details.

Answer (score 4):

Is the location of the treasure changed after each attempt? Wouldn't it be $(10\%)^5$?

Comment: The location changes after each attempt

Comment: as @Edward said. I could ask such a thing in a homework actually... Now Martin, can you figure out what's the chance you never find that treasure?